# How to get aws cloudsearch domain's search endpoint using AWS Java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

hi I want to get search endpoint from cloudsearch domain using AWS Java sdk from offical documentation it is stated that we can use describeDomain method. but it not not mentioned how we use that method exactly anybody have done something similar or have any clue for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the domain status and then get the search endpoint from the domain status.

```
AmazonCloudSearchClient csClient = new AmazonCloudSearchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
    DescribeDomainsRequest describeDomainsRequest = new DescribeDomainsRequest();
    describeDomainsRequest.setDomainNames(domainName);
    DescribeDomainsResult describeDomainsResult = csClient.describeDomains(describeDomainsRequest);
    DomainStatus domainStatus = describeDomainsResult.getDomainStatusList().get(0);
    String searchEndpoint = domainStatus.getSearchService().getEndpoint();
```